# Why is F10 so slow in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, performance, step-into

Question title says it all really - a lot slower than VS2005, with a noticeable (0.5 sec) delay on each key press.

It makes stepping through code a pain.

Comment: are you inside a VM? debug performance blogs in a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joe90 says, SP1 might help; In addition, do you find that performance improves if you close unnecessary windows in the IDE? Do you have source control integration, and if so, what provider do you use (TFS/SourceSafe/etc.)

Answer (score 15):

I've been seeing VERY slow debugging performance in VS2008 SP1 with C++ projects.  Any stepping at all (F10/F11) or even double-clicking different levels in the call stack (even in the same file).

The solution was to disable "Show Threads in Source" on the Debug toolbar.

With that option enabled, each of the above operations took 5-20 seconds.  With it disabled, it's back to normal.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar, and I tip my hat off to you, sir.

Comment: This has been plaguing me for quite a while! Used proc mon to see what was going on which showed lots of searches for a file that can't be found. Did a search on Bing and found your answer - turning off "Show Threads in Source" reduced my 10s F10 to <1s! +1 from me!

Answer (score 2):

What kind of project are you debugging? C#?

I noticed that stepping through code is slowed down when you are monitoring a lot of variables in the Auto and Watch windows. The debugger evaluates any expression shown in these windows after every step.

Try closing these windows and see whether step-through speed increases.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SP1? It might help...

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you've disabled source server integration and enabled "Just my code". I've found that the source server integration stuff can really slow things down, even if you don't actually step into the framework code.

Answer (score 1):

From one of the supplied answers - closing all of the other code windows restored performance to where it should be.

And from one of the others - SP1 also improved things.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Some add-ins also slow down Visual Studio.

My colleague has uninstalled Devexpress for this reason.